# Cannot parsing Json to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I have a WebService, which give me the fallowing Json-String back:

```
"{\"password\" : \"1234\",  \"user\" : \"andreas\"}"
```

I call the webservice and try to parse the returned data like:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                   queue: queue
                       completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {


        if (error || !data) {
           // Handle the error
        } else {
           // Handle the success
           NSError *errorJson = nil;
           NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &errorJson];
           NSString *usr = [responseDict objectForKey:@"user"];
        }
   }
 ];
```

But the resulting NSDictionary looks like:

[image]

What has the effect, that I cannot get the values - for example user.
Can someone help me, what I am doing wrong? - Thank you.

Comment: How did you determine what the JSON string is?

Comment: Apparently it is a dictionaty in a dictionary.

Comment: Evidently that's not precisely what the webservice gives you. What is the value of `data` (preferably converted to a string) before being parsed?

Comment: You are right! - I am doing:
`[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string doSomething(string email, string name) {
    return "{\"password\" : \"1234\",  \"user\" : \"andreas\"}";
}`
and get: 
"{d":"{\"password\" : \"1234\",  \"user\" : \"andreas\"}"}"
but why?

Comment: After reading this thread, it seems you were lying. What you said the WebService was returning wasn't actually what it returned, it was what you thought it was returning. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the debugger screenshot is seems that the server is (for whatever reason) returning
"nested JSON": `responseDict[@"d"]` is a string containing JSON data again, so you have to
apply `NSJSONSerialization` twice:

```
NSError *errorJson = nil;
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:0 error: &errorJson];
NSData *innerJson = [responseDict[@"d"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableDictionary *innerObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:innerJson options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&errorJson];
NSString *usr = [innerObject objectForKey:@"user"];
```

If you have the option, a better solution would be to fix the web service to return
proper JSON data.

Comment: You are right. But I don't know, why I became the wrong result from the WebService. It is a ASP.NET Webservice and there I do only: `return "{\"password\" : \"1234\", \"user\" : \"andreas\"}";`

Comment: @ThomasKehl: I can't answer that, I don't know anything about ASP.NET.

Comment: @ThomasKehl: This is apparently [just something ASP.NET does](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/) when handling AJAX requests.