# Parse a JSON with "unreadable" content

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a JSON from a phonebook-service that Im trying to interpret.

The response gives me 6 items. And the main item is "Data". Inside that item there is a crazy string with many tags.

```
items = [items valueForKeyPath:@"Data"];


{
"qry": "gørild tollefsen aas",
"result": {
    "hitLinesBeforeFilter": 1,
    "approxHits": 1,
    "userID": 56699100,
    "1": {
        "listing": {
            "table": "listing",
            "id": "1070262",
            "duplicates": [
                {
                    "table": "listing",
                    "id": "1070262:0",
                    "idlinje": "P7IBCL",
                    "tlfnr": "99299999",
                    "etternavn": "Aas",
                    "fornavn": "Gørild Tollefsen",
                    "veinavn": "Mo",
                    "husnr": "42",
                    "postnr": "5729",
                    "virkkode": "P",
                    "apparattype": "M",
                    "telco": "MF",
                    "kilde": "P",
                    "prioritet": "0",
                    "fodselsdato": "1988-07-13",
                    "kommunenr": "1252",
                    "kid": "12611829",
                    "poststed": "Modalen",
                    "kommune": "Modalen",
                    "fylke": "Hordaland",
                    "landsdel": "V"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "dummy": null
}
```

}

How can I get "Fornavn", "Etternavn" and "tlfnr" out in a nice way of this in an NSArray?

The content does not look like a JSON to me.

If I tries to debug the count of this array the app crash with the following error:

```
reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f53f80'
```

EDIT:

This nice trick did it for me:

```
NSError *error;
    NSString *tekstdata = [items valueForKeyPath:@"Data"];
    NSDictionary *JSON =
    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [tekstdata dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error: &error];


    items = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"result.1.listing.duplicates"];
```

I had to use the Serialization once more, obvious, since there was a JSON in the original JSON. Thanks for the help. You put me in the right direction.

Comment: Here is the link to the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/adxvoajfc9etpx0/content%20of%20data.txt

Comment: Is this:
`2013-07-29 22:47:43.408 Uni24 Ordre[2032:c07] array : { ...`
part of the data? It looks like the JSON data you have might have extra stuff that is not JSON...

Comment: That looks like "nested JSON". Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283141/cannot-parsing-json-to-nsdictionary.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the JSON -- it validates just fine.

Comment: To get at values within the JSON you must "peel the onion", a layer at a time.  First get "result", then get "1", then "duplicates", then index that 1 item array, then you can access the dictionary with all the details.  But of course you must first parse the JSON into Objective-C objects.

Comment: You are right. I wrote that the JSON did not look like a JSON style to me. But that was before I validated it in a service, and gave me a nice view of it.

Comment: Anyway; I found a trick to solve this. I had to serialization it once more to beth the key path. NSError *error;
        NSString *tekstdata = [items valueForKeyPath:@"Data"];
        NSDictionary *JSON =
        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [tekstdata dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                        options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                          error: &error];
        
        
        items = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"result.1.listing.duplicates"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question as one of the commentators mentioned, peel the Json as if it is an inion.

Use this tool to see how the layers are formed,
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Also, you might want to consider using NSMutableArray so that you can remove and/or re-arrange the array.

Hope I was able to help.

Comment: Yes. Peeling is great. But I found a way to peel the onion at once with NSJSONSerialization (obvious since there was a "json in a json").

Answer (score 0):

In order to get only a few items of interest out of the nested JSON file, I would suggest using the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking#download-and-parse-json) library's `AFJSONRequestOperation` to parse the JSON file and put the results into a `NSDictionary`. 
You can then query the `NSDictionary` with the method `[myDictionary objectForKey:@"Fornavn"]` to retrieve the value.