# Cast to NSDictionary returns nil in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, json-rpc, xcode-6.2

I'm trying to submit a JSON-RPC request in Swift and I was following this ( [Perform POST request in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341858/perform-post-request-in-ios-swift) ) guide.

Unfortunately I'm not able to cast the "result" part of the answer to NSDictionary by doing this:

```
if let responseDictionary = responseObject as? NSDictionary {
    if let errorDictionary = responseDictionary["error"] as? NSDictionary {
        println("error logging in (bad userid/password?): \(errorDictionary)")
    } else if let resultDictionary = responseDictionary["result"] as? NSDictionary {
        println("successfully logged in, refer to resultDictionary for details: \(resultDictionary)")
    } else {
        println("we should never get here")
        println("responseObject = \(responseObject)")
    }
}
```

where responseObject is AnyObject.

My response object looks like this:

```
{
id = 1;
jsonrpc = "2.0";
result = "[{\"ID\":11,\"Name\":\"MyName\",\"LLogon\":\"2015-03-16T13:04:14\"}]";}
```

Comment: "result" isn't a dictionary, it's a string.

Comment: As Hot Licks said, the value of the "result" key is a string. This string is the JSON representation of a dictionary. If possible, fix the server to send a proper response. Otherwise you have to deserialize twice (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283141/cannot-parsing-json-to-nsdictionary for a similar issue).

Comment: We heard you like JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hot Licks and Martin R pointed out this was indeed a server side issue.